# How to display the output of a method on jsf page

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I have a method returning a string.
I want to display it on my JSF page.
How can I do that without setting a property because, output is generated based on method input?

Answer (score 0):

You can display a string on your page likes this;

```
     <h:outputText value="#{backingBean.yourString}"/>
```